# Decreasing trend in semivariogram of nlme model residuals?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, spatial, variogram, spatial-correlation

I am new to spatial statistics and am trying to fit some spatial models using the `nlme` package in R.

I fit three different models, using the same set of predictors for different variable specifications. To assess spatial correlation of the residuals, I would like to produce a semivariogram.

All examples online show a semivariogram that increases from x=0 and then steadies off at the sill, or the point at which there is no spatial autocorrelation. However, the plots of my model residuals show decreasing trends that somewhat level off, and I am unsure of how to interpret this.

When running `plot(Variogram(model))` on each of my model objects, I get the following plots:

[Variogram for model of state-level rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yp0b.png)

[Variogram of state-level import-export ratios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwgeV.png)

[Variogram of state-level late-early ratios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emSXA.png)

1. How should I interpret these decreasing trends?
2. Does this mean that the spatial structure is mis-specified?
3. If the structure is mis-specified, how should I determine the appropriate structure? For reference, I used a Gaussian correlation structure (of the form `corGaus(1, form = ~(longitude+latitude)|year)`), and my models use year as the random-effects grouping variable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: At the scales shown, there is no spatial structure.   They are "pure noise" variograms. Usually that's *good* because it means your models have already captured what structure there might be.

Comment: @whuber Two-sided Moran's I-tests of the model residuals come back as statistically significant across three different neighborhood specifications. How would I reconcile the variograms with that result? My understanding is that both should measure spatial structure in model residuals.

Comment: You would need to explain those tests and show the results before we could understand what's going on.  I, for one, would rely *much* more on the variogram information than on the Moran's I results, for two reasons.  First, the variogram gives more information about the correlation structure. Second, Moran's I relies on distributional assumptions that might not be satisfied.  It's usually more insightful to map a local Moran's I so you can see details of the spatial structure.